# ¿Cómo imprimir el contenido de una variable sin comas y con un espacio?

Tags: php

Soy novato en php y estoy tratando de mostrar el contenido de la variable sin comas entre las palabras que contiene y un espacio o tabulación entre las mismas, les agradeceré su ayuda.

```
<?php echo esc_html($variable);?>
```

**Ahora mismo imprime así:** naranjas,bananas

**Desearía que lo muestre de esta manera:** naranjas bananas (eliminando las comas y asignando un espacio entre las palabras)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una forma sencilla es usar [`str_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.str-replace.php)

```php
$variable = "naranja,banana";
$variable = str_replace(",", " ", $variable);
print $variable;
// naranja banana
```

---

También puedes usar [`explode`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php) para separar el valor de la variable por un delimitador definido, es decir

```php
print explode(",", "hello,world");
// ["hello", "world"]
```

Luego de tener el array, simplemente puedes usar [`implode`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.implode.php)

```php
$variable = "naranja,banana";
$variable = implode(" ", explode(",", $variable));
print $variable;
// naranja banana
```

Comment: Yo pondría primero la forma sencilla de hacerlo, es decir, con `str_replace`. Usar `explode` e `implode` para esto es manipular demasiado los datos.

Answer (score 1):

Tambien puedes usar una expresión regular:

```
$re = '/(,)/m';
$str = 'bananas,naranjas,platanos';
$subst = ' ';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

El resultado es: `bananas naranjas platanos`